# Get a document with a specific _id with mongo-delphi-driver

Tags: mongodb, delphi, mongo-c-driver

I have to perform a query on mongodb, i would like select only a document has a particular _id (type ObjectId).
I use "Strict mode" sintax and in particular the operator *$oid* for compare _id with a string.
But it doesn't work!, I don't now if it is a bug (a bag of mongo-c-driver/mongo-delphi-driver) or if I write wrong code for make a query on ObjectId field.

Below a simple snippet of code, the document with that _id exists but the bson document is nil

```
  var 
    b : TBson;
  begin
    b := mongo.findOne(ns,(BSON(['_id','{','$oid','58c6b6af9b2dcd04ae46844d','}'])));
    if b = nil then
      ShowMessage('No match')
    else
      ShowRecord(b);
  end
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

I also try with this two methods...

```
var
  bb : TBsonBuffer;
  query, b : TBson;
  cursor : TMongoCursor;
begin
  bb := TbsonBuffer.Create();
  bb.startObject('_id');
  bb.append('$oid', PAnsiChar('"58c6b6af9b2dcd04ae46844d"'));
  bb.finishObject();

  query := bb.finish();
  b := mongo.findOne(ns, query);
  if b = nil then
    ShowMessage('No match')
  else
    ShowRecord(b);
end
```

and

```
var
  bb : TBsonBuffer;
  query, b : TBson;
  id : TBsonOID;
begin
  id := TBsonOID.Create('58c6b6af9b2dcd04ae46844d');
  bb := TbsonBuffer.Create();
  bb.startObject('_id');
  bb.append('$oid', id);
  bb.finishObject();

  query := bb.finish();
  b := mongo.findOne(ns, query);
  if b = nil then
    ShowMessage('No match')
  else
    ShowRecord(b);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#input-in-mongo-shell-mode), the strict mode JSON interface is only for use with the HTTP API and command line tools. Drivers are expected to use proper BSON. I think you can do this in Delphi like this:

```
b := mongo.findOne(ns(BSON(['_id',TBsonOID.Create('58c6b6af9b2dcd04ae46844d')])));
```

but I'm not really a delphi guy.

edit: the `TBsonOID` example you added should be like this I think:

```
var
  bb : TBsonBuffer;
  query, b : TBson;
  id : TBsonOID;
begin
  id := TBsonOID.Create('58c6b6af9b2dcd04ae46844d');
  bb := TbsonBuffer.Create();
  // _id isnt a json object it is an oid.
  bb.append('_id', id);
  query := bb.finish();
  b := mongo.findOne(ns, query);
  if b = nil then
    ShowMessage('No match')
  else
    ShowRecord(b);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I use comparison operators like $eq or $gt (on other field) and that work! The problem is on fields with ObjectId type

Comment: that's different. The queries aren't their own bson type, they are just sent as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var FMongoConn : TMongoConnection;
begin
  FMongoConn := TMongoConnection(Connection.CliObj);
  Result := FMongoConn['DataBase'] ['collections'].Dereference(TJsonOid.Create('5EAB21D55C61623E44004B21')).AsJSON;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var oCrs  : IMongoCursor;
    Aux   : String;
begin
   oCrs := FMongoConn['DataBase']['collections'].Find()
    .Match
      .BeginObject('_id')
        .Add('$eq', TJsonOid.Create('5eab21d55c61623e44004b21'))
      .EndObject
    .&End;

  While (oCrs.Next) do
    begin
      Aux := Aux + oCrs.Doc.AsJSON;
    end;

  if Trim(Aux) = '' then
    Memo1.Text := '0'
  else
    Memo1.Text := Aux;
end;
```